# TypeScript strict null checks: how to override library constraint?

Tags: typescript

My code is using the `async` library, specifically this callback type ([source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7f6c79478c8e4d6706f310f0bde4f8088451148f/async/index.d.ts#L9)):

```
interface AsyncResultCallback<T> { (err: Error, result: T): void; }
```

In my TypeScript code with `strictNullChecks` enabled, calling it like this fails:

```
cb(null, someObject);
```

> Error:(239, 16) TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error'.

Now I'm not sure whether the library type definition is wrong or not but let's say it is and the interface should be defined with `err` optional, like this:

```
interface AsyncResultCallback<T> { (err?: Error, result: T): void; }
```

What can I do to persuade TypeScript to allow passing `null` as the first parameter of the callback? I've already tried `"skipLibCheck": true` and `"skipDefaultLibCheck": true` but no joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `skipLibCheck` and `skipDefaultLibCheck` flags won't help in this case because the error is from your code and not from the library you are using.

You have two options (that I can think of):

(1) Pass a non-null value:

```
cb(new Error(), someObject);
```

(2) Try to augment the library:

```
import * as Async from "async";

declare global {
    interface AsyncResultCallback<T> {
        (err: Error | null, result: T): void;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, (1) is not an option because it changes the logic of the code and might break the app, option (2) works, just not exactly that way - but `declare global { ...` works. Option (3) is to type `cb` as `any` if it comes as a parameter, which it does in my case.

Comment: It should work using `declare module "async"`, which is also the right way to do so because using `global` "means" something else. Using `cb: any` works, it will also work with `cb: Function`, but then you lost type safety.

Comment: `declare module "async"` gives me "TS2671: Cannot augment module 'async' because it resolves to a non-module entity.". Possibly related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7148

Comment: Oh, the `async` module exports the types to the global namespace?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7f6c79478c8e4d6706f310f0bde4f8088451148f/async/index.d.ts

Comment: Right. Sorry about that then, you're right using the `declare global` is right then.